# Cannot resolve :spring-securty-core:2.0-RC3 in grails 2.3.8

Tags: spring-security, grails-plugin

I am trying to add spring security core to my grails project in groovy grails toolsuite
but when I tried to compile it, it gives me a below error.

```
Starting process on THBKNB750/10.10.104.32
Loading Grails 2.3.8
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC3 (Use --stacktrace to see the fulltrace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC3 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC3 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC3 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC3
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
Process was killed
```

and here is my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()

        mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }

    dependencies {

    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
        compile ':cache:1.1.2'
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'

        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.13" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.5.1"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
    }
}


Cannot resolve :spring-securty-core:2.0-RC3 in grails 2.3.8
```

if anyone has come across the same problem and has a solution to it, help would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this repo : mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/"

Comment: thank you Julius, I have found my problem was with the proxy server not the repo though but thanks anyway.